# changing some elements of vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I have a vector called x.
 I want to change elements of the vector which are negative to absolute valu of a gaussian random number with std equal to 1 and mean equal to 0. I used below code but it doesn't work. Could anyone suggest a way to do it?

```
 index = (x < 0); x(index) = abs(rand(1,index));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let A be your matrix, to change negative elements to a random numbers, you can use:

```
A = [-1 -2 3 4 5 -1 0 9 ] ;
mu = 0; sigma = 1 ;
idx = A<0 ;
A(idx) =  abs(normrnd(mu,sigma,1,nnz(idx))) ;
```

Problem with your code:

your *index* are logicals, you cannot use logicals to define/ get random numbers. Note that, you need not to use abs(rand)), rand gives you +ve random numbers only.

Comment: It was a mistake. I need a gaussian random number

Comment: It's correct. Thank you. But please change the variance to 1 and mean to zero and use sqrt

Comment: @OliverRange if it is correct then consider accepting it.